# Convert HTML with SWF to Pdf or JPG

Tags: c#, flash, html-to-pdf, html-to-jpeg

My aim is clear. I would like to convert(capture) websites from given url which is HTML page with SWF included to PDF or JPG file.

I need to do it as a batch operation so lib or SaaS is ok for me.

Could anybody recommend any third party solution? It could be library or for example service in the cloud. It can be paid of course.

What I was trying are for example:

1. EVOPDF  library which required flash player to work  but I cannot install flash on the server cause of it is security risky.
2. cloudconvert (BETA)  does not work (swf container is empty)
3. PrinceXml  does not support
4. web2pdfconvert.com  does not work (swf container is empty)

and many others with no results..

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot install flash player how do you expect to capture the SWF data? You need to be able to draw the SWF or it will always be blank.

Comment: There is absolutely no way to render a swf file to an image without software that can interpret swf files..

Comment: Some misunderstanding.. let me explain what i meant. Some 3party software process it on their servers so I dont need flash. I get only pdf output file with static image instead of swf.